# Does an X-Ray tube have an electric field inside of it?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-fields, x-rays, medical-physics

I searched the question on the web, but could not a satisfactory answer.  Anyway, the question is as follows:

The X-Ray tube consists of an anode, which essentially accelerates the electrons, and a cathode, which emits electrons. Since the anode is positively charged, doesn't this generate an electric field inside the tube?

---

I was solving a physics question where they used IVt for determining the electron's energy instead of qV.

Attaching the question and its answer key below:

**Talking about question 10 (a)**

Use IVt = (0.40)(75kV)(20ms)
[image: The Question]

[image: The answer key]

As you may see, the question uses IVt.

Comment: How could there be a potential difference of 75 kilovolts *without* an electric field?

Comment: Note: this is *not* a "check my work" question. Please read before close-voting!

Answer (score 1):

An external high voltage source is connected across the anode and cathode; this voltage creates an electric field inside the tube that accelerates the electrons onto the target.  The voltage is typically 30 to 100 kV.  Wikipedia has a good description under "X-ray tube".